# List Running Commands of All Windows

Tags: process-management, htop, wmctrl

You can list the process ID of each widow with this command:

```
wmctrl -lp
```

Does there exist a command that shows the `running command` of each window (kind of like htop has a column for "Command")?

If not, how could you combine commands to ultimately achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will replace the pid in `wmctrl -lp`’s output with the corresponding command, if one is found:

```
wmctrl -lp | awk '{ pid=$3; cmd="ps -o comm= " pid; while ((cmd | getline command) > 0) { sub(" " pid " ", " " command " ") }; close(cmd) } 1'
```

This obviously won’t work for windows displaying remote processes; it also will give strange results for windows corresponding to sandboxed processes in some cases (*e.g.* Flatpak).

The AWK script reads each line, extracts the pid, and runs `ps -o comm=` to determine the corresponding command; if one is found, it replaces the corresponding pid string with the command.

Comment: nooooice; this is *very* pretty.

Comment: I've got to learn awk!

Answer (score 2):

wow, learned about `wmctrl` today.

Well, this is incredibly close already! Simply take these PIDs, and check their command:

```bsh
for pid in $(wmctrl -lp | tr -s " "| cut -d ' ' -f3); do
#^--|------|--------------|-----------|------------- for .. in .. loop
#   |      |              |           |              
#   \------|--------------|-----------|------------- name of the variable we'll set
#          |              |           |              each iteration
#          |              |           |              
#          \--------------|-----------|------------- $(command): replaces $(..) 
#                         |           |              with output of `command`
#                         |           |              
#                         \-----------|------------- translate character " " by -s:
#                                     |               "squeeze" multiple consecutive 
#                                     |               spaces into one
#                                     |               
#                                     \-------------- cut at ' ', take the 3rd field
  cat "/proc/${pid}/cmdline"
  echo ""
done
```

Also interesting, mabye:

```bsh
for wm_id in $(wmctrl -l | cut -d ' ' -f1); do
  xprop -id "${wm_id}" WM_CLASS
done
```

Comment: I really love the way you commented that command; I've saved it into my notes so I can model after it. Have a Merry Christmas. I recorded [this](https://neartalk.com/ss/JB.mp3) today, just for you.